# How to delete extra rows in mysql when a user updates his/her status via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I made a form that takes the posted youtube url and saves the video ID into the database.
It then retrieves the ID from the database, and inserts it into an iframe.

Only 6 videos are shown, how do I make it so that after a user posts 6 videos, each time he posts a new video the first is deleted?

Basically I want it so that only 6 are stored in the database and each time a new post is submitted the first post is deleted from the database.

Here's what I have now.

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:830px; height:120px; width:680px; background-color:#d0d0d0; font-size:18px; color:#f1f1f1; text-align:center; z-index:0; overflow:none; color:#111;  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;">

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<label for="song">What are you listening to?:</label><br>
<textarea name="song" onfocus="this.select()" id="song" rows="3" cols="71" style="text-align:center;">Post a youtube link here.</textarea>
<input type="submit" class="personal" value="Share" /> 
</form>
</div>



<?php
if ($_POST['song'])
{
$yvid = $_POST['song'];
parse_str( parse_url( $yvid, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );
$yid = $my_array_of_vars['v'];
mysqli_query ($con,"INSERT INTO songs (user_name, ytid) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_name']."','".$yid."')");
}
?>
<div style="position:absolute; display:inline-block; background-color:transparent; height:560px; width:800px; left:810px; top:200px; border:0px; color:#dedede; overflow:auto;">
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM songs WHERE user_name='".$_SESSION['user_name']."' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 6");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
        $ytsong = $row['ytid'];
        $ytun = $row['user_name'];
        $ytt = $row['time'];
        echo "<p style=\"display:inline-block; height:220px; width:200px; text-align:center; padding:20px; border:0px; background-color:transparent;\">";
        echo "<a class=\"vname\" href=\"http://s3v3nl3tt3r5.com/profile.php?username=$ytun\">$ytun</a> posted this at $ytt";
    echo "<iframe style=\"display:inline-block;\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$ytsong\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    echo "<a class=\"personal\" href=\"http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=$ytsong\" target=\"_blank\">Download Mp3</a>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add a `timestamp` column  and delete the earliest once the count was more than your limit.. That way it doesn't effect any primary key you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

create an autoincrement column `id` in `songs` table.

Then insert the new values. After inserting.Get the number of rows and min id :

`'select count(*), min(id) from songs where user_name = '.$user_name;`

check if the count is more than 6 execute a delete statement on min id

```
if($count > 6)
{
"delete from songs where id = $min_id "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you need to take new column in songs table
for example you can take id column auto-increment  and primary 

After Insertion check count of row for that user

SELECT count(*) as total FROM songs WHERE user_name='".$_SESSION['user_name']."' 

if total come greater than six then get minimum  id from songs table and 

SELECT min(ID) FROM songs WHERE user_name='".$_SESSION['user_name']."' 

after getting minimum id you can run delete query 

delete from song where id=$minid
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new column "id" with primary key auto increment and try below query .

```
DELETE FROM songs WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM songs WHERE 
user_name='".$_SESSION['user_name']."' ORDER BY TIME ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: this will always delete a row even if there were less than 6 rows.